# how to filter on all records where a particular field is not blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails controller I want to set an instance variable to all the records that do not have a blank email field.  I know the following would set the variable to all the records, but how do I pare this down to just the records with a non-blank email field?

```
@records = Record.all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
@records = Record.where("email <> ''")
```